# Why is it not displaying the output?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program where I create new nodes and insert items in there.
My problem is when I want to display the items in all the nodes it's not showing it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define NULL 0

struct node{
    int item;
    struct node *next;
}lol;

struct node *head = NULL;
void insertfirst(int ele);
void insertnext(int ele);
void displayelement();

int main()
{
    clrscr();
    int ele,choice;
    printf("Enter element in first node:");
    scanf("%d",&ele);
    do{
        printf("Please select any of the other options\n1.Add element to new node\n2.Display elements\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                    printf("Enter element in node:");
                    scanf("%d",&ele);
                    insertnext(ele);
                    break;
            case 2:
                    displayelement();
                    break;
            default:
                    break;
        }
        getch();
        clrscr();
        displayelement();
    }while(choice < 3);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void insertfirst(int ele)
{
    struct node *p;
    p = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    p -> item = ele;
    p -> next = head;
    head = p;

}

void insertnext(int ele)
{
    struct node *temp;
    struct node *p;
    temp = head;
    p = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp = head;
    p->item = ele;
    p->next = temp ->next;
    temp -> next = p;
}

void displayelement()
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp = head;
    printf("\n The nodes are");
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d",temp -> item);
        temp = temp -> next;
    }

}
```

The program seemed to have worked when i did it directly without using switch case

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define NULL 0

struct node{
            int item;
            struct node *next;
            }lol;

struct node *head = NULL;
void insertfirst(int ele);
void insertnext(int ele);
void displayelement();

int main()
{
clrscr();
int ele;
printf("Enter element in first node:");
scanf("%d",&ele);
insertfirst(ele);
insertnext(ele);
displayelement();
getch();
 return 0;
}

void insertfirst(int ele)
{
    struct node *p;
    p = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    p -> item = ele;
    p -> next = head;
    head = p;

}

void insertnext(int ele)
{
    struct node *temp;
    struct node *p;
    temp = head;
    p = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp = head;
    p->item = ele;
    p->next = temp ->next;
    temp -> next = p;
}

void displayelement()
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp = head;
    printf("\n The nodes are");
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d",temp -> item);
        temp = temp -> next;
    }

}
```

Comment: what is your current output of the program?

Comment: It is not displaying output because you did not debug it.

Comment: regarding the calls to scanf():  always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: @MartinJames, this is site is to help people fix coding problems, not to criticize the OP.

Comment: regarding the calls to malloc(): 1) in C, do not cast the returned value as it is a void* so can be assigned to any pointer and with larger programs, when performing maintenance a type change can easily result in incorrect operation of the program.  2) always check (!= NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: @user3629249 - no, it is not primarily for helping people fix coding problems, it's a repo of useful programming knowledge.  The OP's problem is not lack of coding knowledge, it's lack of debugging skill, and SO is not a debugging service.

Comment: @user3629249 SO contributors are continually critisised on SO and meta for not leaving comments on down/close votes.  If they leave comments on down/close votes, they are critisised.  Well, what would you like?  Comments, but only on nice things?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to call `insertfirst` from the new code leading to undefined behavior in `insertnext` as you dereference a NULL pointer.

Fix the problem by adding

```
insertfirst(ele);
```

after

```
printf("Enter element in first node:");
scanf("%d",&ele);
```

Comment: thank you. can't believe i made such a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

That looks better:

```
void insertfirst(int ele)
{
    head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->item = ele;
    head->next = head;
}

void insertnext(int ele)
{
    struct node *p;
    p = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    p->item = ele;
    p->next = head->next;
    head->next = p;
}
```